# No option to open the app when deploying using a Heroku button

Tags: heroku

**Issue**

When I use the Hasura GraphQL Engine Heroku Button, I don't see a green tick for the `Deploy to Heroku` stage of the deployment and the buttons to manage/view the app are also missing. Reference screenshot:

[image: No Green tick screenshot]

This is how the deployment screen used to look before I ran into this error:

[image: how it used to be]

But this app actually gets deployed as you can see from this screenshot of the dashboard:

[image: app shows up in the dashboard]

The deployment clearly went through without any errors and I can access the `Manage app' button in the app's settings page:

[image: manage app buttons showing up normally]

All the reference screenshots were taken after about 5-10 mins of the deployment process, which is more than enough time for it be completed. The issue was also reproduced consistently multiple times.

**How to reproduce**

1) Go to https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/hasura/graphql-engine-heroku

2) Click on the `Deploy to Heroku` on the top right